# Why does getSystemCpuLoad() return values lower than getProcessCpuLoad()

Tags: java, performance

Recently I am using Netflix OSS Servo's [JvmMetricPoller](https://github.com/Netflix/servo/blob/master/servo-core/src/main/java/com/netflix/servo/publish/JvmMetricPoller.java) to monitor a web application's CPU Usage.

Internally in the JvmMetricPoller it uses `OperatingSystemMXBean` interface to get system metrics.

One strange problem I discover is that the value returned from `getSystemCpuLoad()` is usually lower than the value returned from `getProcessCpuLoad()`.

Why is this happening? How could CPU Usage of a process of the system be higher than the CPU usage of the whole system?

What I'm expecting is that `getSystemCpuLoad()` = `getProcessCpuLoad` + all other process's cpu usages.

Comment: I suspect process load here is "user" load which is usually higher, but could be lower than the time spent in the kernel (System load)

Comment: I would have assumed that @PeterLawrey is right about system load referring only to kernel load.  So I was surprised to see that the javadoc for `getSystemCpuLoad()` actually supports your expectation.  Maybe consecutive calls to the two methods are reporting on different time intervals.  But that wouldn't explain why it's *usually* lower.  Can you quantify *usually*?

Comment: Yep, _usually_ means 95% of the time. The `getSystemCpuLoad()` is _usually_ 0-5% smaller than `getProcessCpuLoad()`. In several data points the `getSystemCpuLoad()` is larger, but there are really very few these data so I think those could be neglected.

Comment: Also, @Peter Lawrey sometimes the process load and the system load are both at high 80%, so I don't think they should be considered something like user usage and the kernel usage. Because it that case user_usage + kernel_usage <= 100% should hold, right?

Comment: What OS and Java version?